# iOS NSMutableArray of sprites exc bad access

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, skspritenode

I have previously populated an NSMutableArrays of bullet sprites for my Advanced Enemy ships within the init of the enemyShip. I have had no memory issues. When I try to add SKSpriteNodes individually to my boss object I get exc_bad_access error which I believe is coming from arc and trying to access a released array.

```
@interface enemyShipAdvanced : NSObject{

NSMutableArray *bulletNodeArray;//holds array of SkSpriteNode bullets.
}
@property NSMutableArray *bulletNodeArray;

@implementation enemyShipAdvanced
@synthesize bulletNodeArray;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    bulletNodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//puts 4 sprite nodes in the array.
    bulletNodeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bulletAdv.png"],[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bulletAdv.png"], [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bulletAdv.png"], [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bulletAdv.png"], nil];
    return self;
}
```

//The above code works fine with no memory errors.

```
@interface enemyBoss : NSObject {
NSMutableArray *bulletNodeArray;//holds array of SkSpriteNode bullets.
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *bulletNodeArray;

@implementation enemyBoss
@synthesize bulletNodeArray;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];    

    self.bulletNodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    SKTextureAtlas *electricAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"electricImages"];
    SKTexture *e0 = [electricAtlas textureNamed:@"electricShot0.png"];

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){//should create an array of 12 sprites that the boss can use.
        SKSpriteNode *electricSprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:e0];       
        [self.bulletNodeArray addObject:electricSprite];//adds bullet sprite to Mutable array.

    }
```

//The above code for enemy boss give exc_bad_access error half the time. I know the texture atlas is not the problem because I've tried adding regular Sprites the same way and still received the same problem. can I populate a NSMutableArray in a loop like this without receiving these memory leaks?

Comment: Have you set up exception breakpoints?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger ?

Comment: I have a break point set up to break on any objective C exception and another to break a couple of seconds after the boss object is created. When there is no exc_bad_access error the array populated with 12 unique SkSpriteNodes. I'm not sure how to use the debugger properly.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had a misplaced variable in the code. thanks for the help!